# How did this pass as valid

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, triage

On stack overflow I reviewed this:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9936206

What I saw was a lot of bullet points to a project. I saw no code or any real question.

How is that valid?

Comment: "how is that valid". Because its miles away from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278046/how-to-create-a-new-database-like-mysql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That question is pretty good, I wouldn't say its "Unsalvagable" at all, even "Needs Improvement" is a stretch.

It:

- Could be construed as a library recommendation request but is phrased cleverly to allow straight up coding solutions as well
- Fully explains the context (wants to test a compiler)
- Shows what the OP tried
- Asks an answerable question (how to construct such at test)

Apart from *smelling* like a recommendation question, I see no reason why "Looks Good" isn't the correct review (and 7 people upvoted it, so I'm not alone!)

Comment: I was about to hop on that *open-ended* sentence you posted earlier haha

Comment: @xPeke Yeah, sorry about that :)

Comment: Yeah I only saw 7 upvotes after I had said Too Broad. I was just thinking that most of that falls under recommendation (Compiler, structure etc...). That and there was no code. I guess I am slightly misunderstanding what is valid or is not.